# How to match a response with 'OR' Condition

Tags: karate

I a trying to match a response with 'OR' condition as below .
Here i have two condition a empty array to match
ex :

- match EmptyArrayresonse == "#? _ == {[]} || _ == []"

o/p
SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:7 Expected an operand but found ]
_ == {[]} || _ == []
^

I am expection to get a match with 'OR' condition

Comment: please give a specific example. `{[]}` is not valid json and makes no sense